# Invalid symbol kind: NamedType

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-forms-designer

I have a project written by someone else and I have a problem with one of the forms.

When I try to open Form1 in "Design mode" Visual Studio 2017 shows the error screen and returns "Failed to parse method 'InitializeComponent'. The parser reported the following error 'Invalid symbol kind: NamedType'. Please look in the Task List for potential errors."

```
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.Serialization.CodeDom.VSCodeDomParser.OnMethodPopulateStatements(Object sender, EventArgs e)
at System.CodeDom.CodeMemberMethod.get_Statements()
at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.TypeCodeDomSerializer.Deserialize(IDesignerSerializationManager manager, CodeTypeDeclaration declaration)
at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.CodeDomDesignerLoader.PerformLoad(IDesignerSerializationManager manager)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.Serialization.CodeDom.VSCodeDomDesignerLoader.PerformLoad(IDesignerSerializationManager serializationManager)
at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.BasicDesignerLoader.BeginLoad(IDesignerLoaderHost host)
```

I found some solution here on stackoverflow when new form was created and added everything manually. I could do it this by same way but I would like to know where is the problem.

Sorry for names of some components in Czech language.

Whole code:

```
namespace LektorHra
{
partial class Lektor
{
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing && this.components != null)
            this.components.Dispose();
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        this.components = (IContainer)new Container();
        this.ChatBox = new System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox();
        this.textBox = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
        this.comboBox = new System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox();
        this.buttonOdeslat = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        this.groupBox1 = new System.Windows.Forms.GroupBox();
        this.kvaSupA = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        this.supSupervizeA = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        this.finSuperA = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        this.VyrobaSupervizeA = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        this.AlabelKvalita = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.AlabelSupply = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.AlabelFinPer = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.AlabelVyroba = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.groupBox2 = new System.Windows.Forms.GroupBox();
        this.kvalitaSupervizreB = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        this.supchainSupervizeB = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        this.finSupervizeB = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        this.vyrobaSupervizeB = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        this.BlabelKvalita = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.BlabelSupply = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.BlabelFinPer = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.BlabelVyroba = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.groupBox3 = new System.Windows.Forms.GroupBox();
        this.kvalitaSupervizeC = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        this.supplzSupervizeC = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        this.vyrobaFinancniC = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        this.vyrobaSupervizeC = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        this.ClabelKvalita = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.ClabelSupply = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.ClabelFinancni = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.ClabelVyroba = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.timer1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer(this.components);
        this.labelCas = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.label2 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.buttonStart = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        this.label3 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.textBoxDelkaKola = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
        this.timerStopky = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer(this.components);
        this.buttonIniNacteni = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        this.label1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.label4 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.textBoxRozpocet = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
        this.textBoxPocetPozVy = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
        this.groupBox4 = new System.Windows.Forms.GroupBox();
        this.label5 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.textBoxPocetKol = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
        this.buttonVytvoreniHry = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        this.labelKolo = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.groupBox5 = new System.Windows.Forms.GroupBox();
        this.buttonVyhodnoceni = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        this.buttonUkonceniKola = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        this.groupBox1.SuspendLayout();
        this.groupBox2.SuspendLayout();
        this.groupBox3.SuspendLayout();
        this.groupBox4.SuspendLayout();
        this.groupBox5.SuspendLayout();
        this.SuspendLayout();
        this.ChatBox.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(12, 12);
        this.ChatBox.Name = "ChatBox";
        this.ChatBox.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(592, 342);
        this.ChatBox.TabIndex = 0;
        this.ChatBox.Text = "";
        this.textBox.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(13, 361);
        this.textBox.Name = "textBox";
        this.textBox.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(591, 20);
        this.textBox.TabIndex = 1;
        this.comboBox.FormattingEnabled = true;
        this.comboBox.Items.AddRange(new object[]
        {
    (object) "Všem",
    (object) "Oddělení výroby",
    (object) "Finanční a personální oddělení",
    (object) "Oddělení Supply Chain",
    (object) "Oddělení kvality a BOZP"
        });
        this.comboBox.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(13, 401);
        this.comboBox.Name = "comboBox";
        this.comboBox.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(121, 21);
        this.comboBox.TabIndex = 2;
        this.buttonOdeslat.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(153, 398);
        this.buttonOdeslat.Name = "buttonOdeslat";
        this.buttonOdeslat.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 23);
        this.buttonOdeslat.TabIndex = 3;
        this.buttonOdeslat.Text = "ODESLAT";
        this.buttonOdeslat.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        this.buttonOdeslat.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.buttonOdeslat_Click);
        this.groupBox1.Controls.Add((System.Windows.Forms.Control)this.kvaSupA);
        this.groupBox1.Controls.Add((System.Windows.Forms.Control)this.supSupervizeA);
        this.groupBox1.Controls.Add((System.Windows.Forms.Control)this.finSuperA);
        this.groupBox1.Controls.Add((System.Windows.Forms.Control)this.VyrobaSupervizeA);
        this.groupBox1.Controls.Add((System.Windows.Forms.Control)this.AlabelKvalita);
        this.groupBox1.Controls.Add((System.Windows.Forms.Control)this.AlabelSupply);
        this.groupBox1.Controls.Add((System.Windows.Forms.Control)this.AlabelFinPer);
        this.groupBox1.Controls.Add((System.Windows.Forms.Control)this.AlabelVyroba);
        this.groupBox1.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 9.75f, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, (byte)238);
        this.groupBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(13, 465);
        this.groupBox1.Name = "groupBox1";
        this.groupBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(200, 115);
        this.groupBox1.TabIndex = 4;
        this.groupBox1.TabStop = false;
        this.groupBox1.Text = "Tým A";
        this.kvaSupA.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 8.25f, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, (byte)238);
        this.kvaSupA.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(140, 84);
        this.kvaSupA.Name = "kvaSupA";
        this.kvaSupA.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(48, 21);
        this.kvaSupA.TabIndex = 13;
        this.kvaSupA.Text = "zobraz";
        this.kvaSupA.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        this.kvaSupA.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.kvaSupA_Click);
        this.supSupervizeA.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 8.25f, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, (byte)238);
        this.supSupervizeA.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(140, 61);
        this.supSupervizeA.Name = "supSupervizeA";
        this.supSupervizeA.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(48, 21);
        this.supSupervizeA.TabIndex = 14;
        this.supSupervizeA.Text = "zobraz";
        this.supSupervizeA.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        this.supSupervizeA.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.supSupervizeA_Click);
        this.finSuperA.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 8.25f, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, (byte)238);
        this.finSuperA.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(140, 36);
        this.finSuperA.Name = "finSuperA";
        this.finSuperA.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(48, 21);
        this.finSuperA.TabIndex = 13;
        this.finSuperA.Text = "zobraz";
        this.finSuperA.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        this.finSuperA.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.finSuperA_Click);
        this.VyrobaSupervizeA.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 8.25f, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, (byte)238);
        this.VyrobaSupervizeA.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(140, 12);
        this.VyrobaSupervizeA.Name = "VyrobaSupervizeA";
        this.VyrobaSupervizeA.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(48, 21);
        this.VyrobaSupervizeA.TabIndex = 4;
        this.VyrobaSupervizeA.Text = "zobraz";
        this.VyrobaSupervizeA.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        this.VyrobaSupervizeA.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.VyrobaSupervizeA_Click);
        this.AlabelKvalita.AutoSize = true;
        this.AlabelKvalita.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 9f, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, (byte)238);
        this.AlabelKvalita.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(6, 86);
        this.AlabelKvalita.Name = "AlabelKvalita";
        this.AlabelKvalita.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(88, 15);
        this.AlabelKvalita.TabIndex = 3;
        this.AlabelKvalita.Text = "Kvalita a BOZP";
        this.AlabelSupply.AutoSize = true;
        this.AlabelSupply.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 9f, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, (byte)238);
        this.AlabelSupply.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(6, 64);
        this.AlabelSupply.Name = "AlabelSupply";
        this.AlabelSupply.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(79, 15);
        this.AlabelSupply.TabIndex = 2;
        this.AlabelSupply.Text = "Supply Chain";
        this.AlabelFinPer.AutoSize = true;
        this.AlabelFinPer.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 9f, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, (byte)238);
        this.AlabelFinPer.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(6, 42);
        this.AlabelFinPer.Name = "AlabelFinPer";
        this.AlabelFinPer.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(128, 15);
        this.AlabelFinPer.TabIndex = 1;
        this.AlabelFinPer.Text = "Finanční a personální ";
        this.AlabelVyroba.AutoSize = true;
        this.AlabelVyroba.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 9f, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, (byte)238);
        this.AlabelVyroba.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(6, 18);
        this.AlabelVyroba.Name = "AlabelVyroba";
        this.AlabelVyroba.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(44, 15);
        this.AlabelVyroba.TabIndex = 0;
        this.AlabelVyroba.Text = "Výroba";
        this.groupBox2.Controls.Add((System.Windows.Forms.Control)this.kvalitaSupervizreB);
        this.groupBox2.Controls.Add((System.Windows.Forms.Control)this.supchainSupervizeB);
        this.groupBox2.Controls.Add((System.Windows.Forms.Control)this.finSupervizeB);
        this.groupBox2.Controls.Add((System.Windows.Forms.Control)this.vyrobaSupervizeB);
        this.groupBox2.Controls.Add((System.Windows.Forms.Control)this.BlabelKvalita);
        this.groupBox2.Controls.Add((System.Windows.Forms.Control)this.BlabelSupply);
        this.groupBox2.Controls.Add((System.Windows.Forms.Control)this.BlabelFinPer);
        this.groupBox2.Controls.Add((System.Windows.Forms.Control)this.BlabelVyroba);
        this.groupBox2.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 9.75f, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, (byte)238);
        this.groupBox2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(221, 465);
        this.groupBox2.Name = "groupBox2";
        this.groupBox2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(200, 115);
        this.groupBox2.TabIndex = 5;
        this.groupBox2.TabStop = false;
        this.groupBox2.Text = "Tým B";
        this.kvalitaSupervizreB.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 8.25f, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, (byte)238);
        this.kvalitaSupervizreB.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(146, 84);
        this.kvalitaSupervizreB.Name = "kvalitaSupervizreB";
        this.kvalitaSupervizreB.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(48, 21);
        this.kvalitaSupervizreB.TabIndex = 16;
        this.kvalitaSupervizreB.Text = "zobraz";
        this.kvalitaSupervizreB.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        this.kvalitaSupervizreB.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.kvalitaSupervizreB_Click);
        this.supchainSupervizeB.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 8.25f, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, (byte)238);
        this.supchainSupervizeB.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(146, 61);
        this.supchainSupervizeB.Name = "supchainSupervizeB";
        this.supchainSupervizeB.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(48, 21);
        this.supchainSupervizeB.TabIndex = 18;
        this.supchainSupervizeB.Text = "zobraz";
        this.supchainSupervizeB.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        this.supchainSupervizeB.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.supchainSupervizeB_Click);
        this.finSupervizeB.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 8.25f, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, (byte)238);
        this.finSupervizeB.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(146, 36);
        this.finSupervizeB.Name = "finSupervizeB";
        this.finSupervizeB.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(48, 21);
        this.finSupervizeB.TabIndex = 17;
        this.finSupervizeB.Text = "zobraz";
        this.finSupervizeB.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        this.finSupervizeB.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.finSupervizeB_Click);
        this.vyrobaSupervizeB.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 8.25f, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, (byte)238);
        this.vyrobaSupervizeB.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(146, 12);
        this.vyrobaSupervizeB.Name = "vyrobaSupervizeB";
        this.vyrobaSupervizeB.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(48, 21);
        this.vyrobaSupervizeB.TabIndex = 15;
        this.vyrobaSupervizeB.Text = "zobraz";
        this.vyrobaSupervizeB.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        this.vyrobaSupervizeB.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.vyrobaSupervizeB_Click);
        this.BlabelKvalita.AutoSize = true;
        this.BlabelKvalita.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 9f, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, (byte)238);
        this.BlabelKvalita.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(6, 86);
        this.BlabelKvalita.Name = "BlabelKvalita";
        this.BlabelKvalita.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(88, 15);
        this.BlabelKvalita.TabIndex = 3;
        this.BlabelKvalita.Text = "Kvalita a BOZP";
        this.BlabelSupply.AutoSize = true;
        this.BlabelSupply.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 9f, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, (byte)238);
        this.BlabelSupply.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(6, 64);
        this.BlabelSupply.Name = "BlabelSupply";
        this.BlabelSupply.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(79, 15);
        this.BlabelSupply.TabIndex = 2;
        this.BlabelSupply.Text = "Supply Chain";
        this.BlabelFinPer.AutoSize = true;
        this.BlabelFinPer.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 9f, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, (byte)238);
        this.BlabelFinPer.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(6, 42);
        this.BlabelFinPer.Name = "BlabelFinPer";
        this.BlabelFinPer.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(125, 15);
        this.BlabelFinPer.TabIndex = 1;
        this.BlabelFinPer.Text = "Finanční a personální";
        this.BlabelVyroba.AutoSize = true;
        this.BlabelVyroba.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 9f, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, (byte)238);
        this.BlabelVyroba.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(6, 18);
        this.BlabelVyroba.Name = "BlabelVyroba";
        this.BlabelVyroba.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(44, 15);
        this.BlabelVyroba.TabIndex = 0;
        this.BlabelVyroba.Text = "Výroba";
                    this.groupBox4.Controls.Add((System.Windows.Forms.Control)this.label5);
        this.groupBox4.Controls.Add((System.Windows.Forms.Control)this.textBoxPocetKol);
        this.groupBox4.Controls.Add((System.Windows.Forms.Control)this.buttonVytvoreniHry);
        this.groupBox4.Controls.Add((System.Windows.Forms.Control)this.buttonIniNacteni);
        this.groupBox4.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 9.75f, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Italic, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, (byte)238);
        this.groupBox4.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(722, 12);
        this.groupBox4.Name = "groupBox4";
        this.groupBox4.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(157, 126);
        this.groupBox4.TabIndex = 17;
        this.groupBox4.TabStop = false;
        this.groupBox4.Text = "Vytvoření hry";
        this.label5.AutoSize = true;
        this.label5.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 9f, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, (byte)238);
        this.label5.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(6, 57);
        this.label5.Name = "label5";
        this.label5.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(70, 15);
        this.label5.TabIndex = 15;
        this.label5.Text = "Počet kol:";
        this.textBoxPocetKol.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 9f, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, (byte)238);
        this.textBoxPocetKol.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(82, 54);
        this.textBoxPocetKol.Name = "textBoxPocetKol";
        this.textBoxPocetKol.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(38, 21);
        this.textBoxPocetKol.TabIndex = 14;
        this.buttonVytvoreniHry.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(76, 97);
        this.buttonVytvoreniHry.Name = "buttonVytvoreniHry";
        this.buttonVytvoreniHry.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 23);
        this.buttonVytvoreniHry.TabIndex = 13;
        this.buttonVytvoreniHry.Text = "OK";
        this.buttonVytvoreniHry.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        this.buttonVytvoreniHry.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.buttonVytvoreniHry_Click);
        this.labelKolo.AutoSize = true;
        this.labelKolo.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 9f, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, (byte)238);
        this.labelKolo.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(114, (int)sbyte.MaxValue);
        this.labelKolo.Name = "labelKolo";
        this.labelKolo.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(0, 15);
        this.labelKolo.TabIndex = 18;
        this.groupBox5.Controls.Add((System.Windows.Forms.Control)this.buttonUkonceniKola);
        this.groupBox5.Controls.Add((System.Windows.Forms.Control)this.label4);
        this.groupBox5.Controls.Add((System.Windows.Forms.Control)this.labelKolo);
        this.groupBox5.Controls.Add((System.Windows.Forms.Control)this.labelCas);
        this.groupBox5.Controls.Add((System.Windows.Forms.Control)this.label2);
        this.groupBox5.Controls.Add((System.Windows.Forms.Control)this.textBoxPocetPozVy);
        this.groupBox5.Controls.Add((System.Windows.Forms.Control)this.buttonStart);
        this.groupBox5.Controls.Add((System.Windows.Forms.Control)this.textBoxRozpocet);
        this.groupBox5.Controls.Add((System.Windows.Forms.Control)this.label3);
        this.groupBox5.Controls.Add((System.Windows.Forms.Control)this.textBoxDelkaKola);
        this.groupBox5.Controls.Add((System.Windows.Forms.Control)this.label1);
        this.groupBox5.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 9.75f, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Italic, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, (byte)238);
        this.groupBox5.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(641, 150);
        this.groupBox5.Name = "groupBox5";
        this.groupBox5.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(333, 204);
        this.groupBox5.TabIndex = 19;
        this.groupBox5.TabStop = false;
        this.groupBox5.Text = "Vytváření jednotlivých kol";
        this.buttonVyhodnoceni.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(854, 361);
        this.buttonVyhodnoceni.Name = "buttonVyhodnoceni";
        this.buttonVyhodnoceni.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(120, 23);
        this.buttonVyhodnoceni.TabIndex = 20;
        this.buttonVyhodnoceni.Text = "Vyhodnocení hry";
        this.buttonVyhodnoceni.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        this.buttonVyhodnoceni.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.buttonVyhodnoceni_Click);
        this.buttonUkonceniKola.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(182, (int)sbyte.MaxValue);
        this.buttonUkonceniKola.Name = "buttonUkonceniKola";
        this.buttonUkonceniKola.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(133, 23);
        this.buttonUkonceniKola.TabIndex = 19;
        this.buttonUkonceniKola.Text = "Ukončit akt. kolo";
        this.buttonUkonceniKola.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        this.buttonUkonceniKola.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.buttonUkonceniKola_Click);
        this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6f, 13f);
        this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
        this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(1008, 729);
        this.Controls.Add((System.Windows.Forms.Control)this.buttonVyhodnoceni);
        this.Controls.Add((System.Windows.Forms.Control)this.groupBox5);
        this.Controls.Add((System.Windows.Forms.Control)this.groupBox4);
        this.Controls.Add((System.Windows.Forms.Control)this.groupBox3);
        this.Controls.Add((System.Windows.Forms.Control)this.groupBox2);
        this.Controls.Add((System.Windows.Forms.Control)this.groupBox1);
        this.Controls.Add((System.Windows.Forms.Control)this.buttonOdeslat);
        this.Controls.Add((System.Windows.Forms.Control)this.comboBox);
        this.Controls.Add((System.Windows.Forms.Control)this.textBox);
        this.Controls.Add((System.Windows.Forms.Control)this.ChatBox);
        this.Name = nameof(Lektor);
        this.Text = nameof(Lektor);
        this.FormClosing += new System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventHandler(this.Lektor_FormClosing);
        this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.Lektor_Load);
        this.groupBox1.ResumeLayout(false);
        this.groupBox1.PerformLayout();
        this.groupBox2.ResumeLayout(false);
        this.groupBox2.PerformLayout();
        this.groupBox3.ResumeLayout(false);
        this.groupBox3.PerformLayout();
        this.groupBox4.ResumeLayout(false);
        this.groupBox4.PerformLayout();
        this.groupBox5.ResumeLayout(false);
        this.groupBox5.PerformLayout();
        this.ResumeLayout(false);
        this.PerformLayout();
    }

     }
}
```

Edit:
The problem was with these lines
this.Name = nameof(Lektor);
this.Text = nameof(Lektor);

When I deleted them, problem disappeared.

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/66eb306f-ce28-46bf-88d0-fea2b3876ce5/c-failed-to-parse-method-initializecomponent-the-parser-reported-the-following-error-invalid?forum=winforms may be worth a read.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

try like this

before

```
this.Name = nameof(Lektor);
this.Text = nameof(Lektor);
```

changed

```
this.Name = "Lektor";
this.Text = "Lektor";
```

Comment: My day is saved

Comment: Thank you. Saved my ***